# Passing an array into WPDB Query for Related Posts

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I have the following code below. I know this isn't the most efficient way of grabbing related posts. I'm new to querying databases, is there a way to throw an array in there to query multiple terms that could be selected? Instead of what I am doing now and just grabbing the first key of the array.

```
<?php
// Get The Related Term
$terms = array();
foreach(wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'series') as $term){
    $terms[] = $term->slug;
};

// Grab The First Term From The Array
$related_term = array_shift(array_values($terms));

// Query The Related Posts
$related_posts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'sermon' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'series'
    AND $wpdb->terms.slug = '$related_term'
    AND $wpdb->posts.ID <> $post->ID
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
    "
);
foreach ($related_posts as $related) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($related->ID).'">'.get_the_title($related->ID).'</a></li>';
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to get posts from different terms in a more propper way. Have a look at this quick example

```
$related_posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // all posts
    'post_type' => 'sermon',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'series',
                'field' => 'slug', // or id
                'terms' => $term1->slug // or id
                'include_children' => false // do no include the posts in the child terms
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'series',
                'field' => 'slug', // or id
                'terms' => $term2->slug // or id
                'include_children' => false // do no include the posts in the child terms
            ), //etc...
    )
));
```

All you have to do is get all the terms for the current post and loop and push them to the get_posts tax_query array.

Comment: This would not allow me to do it dynamically though.